# Unable to download apps from Play Store using cellular data

Tags: 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g-4g

Hi while i am in home network i can easily able to download anything in playstore with my mobile data when am in roaming that time i cant able to download anything from play store it is showing downloading when i click on install but it wont download....please help me what to do

Comment: It appears your shift key may also be broken.  Perhaps you can update your questions after getting it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on android - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211038

It's reported almost 6 months back, since may! ( In developer preview).
It's supposed to be released in the next update.